# JavaScript plugin false positives for function complexity and function length

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

We are constantly getting false positive issues from our JavaScript plugins regarding the function complexity and function length rules.

The reason is that we have functions that are written inside function and the outer functions get the issues.
I understand that technically the complexity looks at everything, 
but isn't there a way of getting the plugin to look only at the functions themselves?
(other than marking it as false positive)

Server version 4.5.6
JavaScript plugin version 2.9

There is a complexity issue of rule "javascript:FunctionComplexity" (complexity=25) for the redeployCtrl function.

This is the code, as you can see the actual complexity is from the inner functions.

is there a way around this other than marking the issue as false positive (and losing the complexity issue for the inner functions) or writing a custom rule?

thanks.

```
function redeployCtrl($scope, utilService, $filter, $location, generalSettings, $uibModalInstance, $uibModal, $timeout,scheme) {
$scope.openStart = openStart;
$scope.isSubmitable = isSubmitable;
$scope.ipCheckbox = ipCheckbox;
$scope.deploy = deploy;
$scope.init = init;
$scope.cancel = cancel;

function init() {
    $scope.scheme = scheme;
    $scope.loading = 'false';
    $scope.envSchemes = [];
    $scope.isPermanent = false;
    $scope.permanent = {};
    $scope.scheme.Scheme.Description = null;
    $scope.scheme.Scheme.ExpTime = null;

    var max = generalSettings.CalendarEndDate;
    $scope.maxDate = new Date();
    $scope.maxDate.setMonth($scope.maxDate.getMonth() + max);
    $scope.minDate = new Date();
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate.setDate($scope.minDate.getDate() + generalSettings.MinExpirationDate);
    $scope.dateOptions = {
        'year-format': 'yyyy',
        'starting-day': 1
    };

    utilService.post(generalSettings.serverPath + 'envscheme/ListSupervisors/', { })
      .then(function (data) {
          $scope.supervisors = data;
      }).catch(function (data) {
          utilService.setError(data.ExceptionMessage, "Failed to retrieve data", "img_error");
      });


    utilService.post(generalSettings.serverPath + 'envscheme/ListPermReasons/', { })
    .then(function (data) {
        $scope.permReasons = data;

    }).catch(function (data) {
        utilService.setError(data.ExceptionMessage, "Failed to retrieve data", "img_error");
    });
}

function openStart() {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.startOpened = true;
    });
}

function deploy(scheme, isPermanent) {
    if (isPermanent) {
        scheme.Scheme.ExpTime = '01/01/9999';
        scheme.Scheme.ApprovedBy = $scope.permanent.approvedBy;
        if ($scope.permanent.mainReason === 'Other') {
            scheme.Scheme.Reason = $scope.permanent.customReason;
        } else {
            scheme.Scheme.Reason = $scope.permanent.mainReason;
        }
    } else {
        $scope.scheme.Scheme.ExpTime = utilService.getFormattedDate($scope.scheme.Scheme.ExpTime);
    }
    $scope.loading = 'true';

    utilService.post(generalSettings.serverPath + 'envscheme/ReCreateEnv', scheme)
     .then(function (data) {
         if (data.Success) {
             utilService.alertAmpm("Deploy started successfuly", "Info", "img_information");
             $location.path("/MyEnvironments");
         }
         else {
             utilService.alertAmpm(data.Reason, "Failed to Re-Deploy", "img_error");
             $scope.loading = 'false';
         }
         if (data.Reason.indexOf("Session was not found") < -1) {
             sessionStorage.clear();
             $scope.loading = 'false';
         }
     }).catch(function (data) {
         utilService.setError(data.ExceptionMessage, "Failed to Re-Deploy", "img_error");
         $scope.loading = 'false';
     });
}

function isSubmitable(invalid, modules) {
    if (!invalid) {

        for (var i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
            if (modules[i].ipchkBox) {
                if (!modules[i].OS.Parameters.IP) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function ipCheckbox(checkBox, name) {
    if (!checkBox) {
        var name1 = "ipText" + name;
        $('[name=' + name1 + ']').val('');
        $scope.scheme.Scheme.modules[name].OS.Parameters = new Object();
    }
}

function cancel() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
}
```

Roy.

Comment: Please provide an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with code snippets and SonarQube issues. Also detail your environment, especially the plugin version.

Comment: I rushed this, sorry. I am adding the details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These rules force the coding with less nested functions. They ignore some cases like IIFE or practices accepted in some frameworks (AMD, Angular). But that's obviously is not your case.

So if you think that this coding practice is not for you, the only thing you can do is to disable the rules (and may create [custom](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Custom+Rules+for+JavaScript) rules counting only lines you want).

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer

Comment: @Elena Vilchik: how exactly can we make it to ignore Angular intricacies, but still warn for "regular" code? Mind you that this seems to be an existing issue, and hence I don't understand how is this answer the question. Thanks. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/M6f5Neze7Jw